# edit AssocList by key

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a recursive function that replaces the CellType by the Cell. Just like this:

`> editBoard [((2,2),Mine),((2,3),Mine),((3,2),Mine)]((2, 4), Flag)`

`> [((2,2),Mine),((2,3),Flag),((3,2),Mine)]`

This is what I have so far:

```
editBoard :: Board -> (Cell, CellType) -> Board
editBoard (Board ((x, y):xs)) (a, b) 
         | x == a = (Board ((x, b) : xs))
         | otherwise = ((x, y) : editBoard (Board xs) (a, b))
```

I keep getting an error that says

> Couldn't match expected type `‘[(Cell, CellType)]’`
>                     with actual type `‘Board’`

even though Board is defined as

```
newtype Board = Board [(Cell,CellType)] deriving(Eq)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `otherwise` returns a list. Indeed, but your type signature says it should return a `Board`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your function says you are returning a `Board`, but the `otherwise` clause will return a list:

```
editBoard :: Board -> (Cell, CellType) -> Board
editBoard (Board ((x, y):xs)) (a, b) 
         | x == a = (Board ((x, b) : xs))
         | otherwise = ((x, y) : editBoard (Board xs) (a, b))
```

I think however you make things too complicated. It might be better to make a helper function that works with a list of `(Cell, CellType)` objects, and returns such list, and let the `editBoard` wrap and unwrap the content:

```
editBoard :: Board -> (Cell, CellType) -> Board
editBoard (Board bs) xy@(x0, y0) = Board (go bs)
    where go :: [(Cell, CellType)] -> [(Cell, CellType)]
          go … = …
```

I leave implementing `go` as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still struggling... I don't really get what go is supposed to do. I'm trying to change the value (CellType) at the key (Cell) in the given Board.

Comment: @nenmuna: you can not *change* a value in Haskell, you can only construct a *new* list. So you should recursion to "walk" through the list. If a key matches, you yield a new 2-tuple, and the rest of the list. If you reach the end of the list. Then you return the empty list.